# My Quiz isn't replacing the previous question

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner coder so the JavaScript code isn't very good. I am trying to make a math quiz and I have gotten the questions to appear and the next question to appear after I click the quiz button. For some reason the next question appears underneath the previous question but I want it to replace the question instead. I have looked over my code numerous times and have asked a couple of my friends who are a bit more experienced and they can't find the problem either.

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Maths Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mathquiz.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="quizquestions"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mathquiz.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
let gameMode = prompt('Which gamemode would you like to play? There is easy, medium or hard.');//This value will be changed in the while loop below depending on the users answers  
let gameDifficulty=0;  //This will get changed. and will tell the program if they are using the easy, medium or hard array
let questionNumber = 0;  // This will be used to display each question without much code
let finishedQuestions = false;  // This will be set to true after all the questions are answered. It will stop the questions from being displayed.
let score = 0;  //this will be used to display their score and help the programm decide which message should be displayed at the end of the game
let currentQuestion;
let optionA;  
let optionB;
let optionC;
let optionD;
let option;
let options;
let box;
let questions = [ //this is my multidimentional array containing all the questions and answers
    [
        ['What is 5+9?', '12', '14', '16', '18', 'B'],//The letter at the end will help me find out if they selected the correct asnwer.
        ['What is 8-4?', '12', '2', '4', '6', 'C'],
        ['What is 9-3?', '6', '12', '27', '3', 'A'],
        ['What is 9+4?', '5', '13', '15', '16', 'B'],
        ['What is 34-9?', '33', '26', '25', '28', 'C'],
        ['What is 18+11?', '30', '27', '29', '32', 'C'],
        ['What is 78-21?', '57', '60', '63', '67', 'A'],
        ['What is 58+13?', '59', '64', '68', '71', 'D']
    ],
    [
        ['What is 5x3?', '10', '12', '15', '18', 'C'],
        ['What is 12/4?', '3', '4', '5', '2', 'A'],
        ['What is 8x6?', '42', '47', '48', '51', 'A'],
        ['What is 37+105?', '137', '153', '146', '142', 'D'],
        ['What is 9x8?', '69', '73', '68', '72', 'D'],
        ['What is 321-123?', '198', '189', '199', '188', 'A'],
        ['What is 12x9?', '99', '132', '108', '117', 'C'],
        ['What is 143/11?', '8', '10', '17', '14', 'D']
    ],
    [
        ['What is 45x32?', '1458', '1435', '1440', '1470', 'C'],
        ['What is 256/16?', '16', '19', '14', '22', 'A'],
        ['What is (5x6)^2+3?', '876', '967', '903', '954', 'C'],
        ['What is a+a=b b/a=a b<0 what is a?', '-1', '3', '2', '0', 'C'],
        ['What is 187+245+216?', '652', '648', '672', '649', 'C'],
        ['What is 87x24?', '2068', '2078', '2088', '2098', 'C'],
        ['What is ((9/3)(5x8))/6+57)?','66', '77', '88', '99', 'B'],
        ['What is (23x65)/23?', '60', '65', '70', '75', 'B']
    ]
];

if (gameMode == 'easy'){
    gameDifficulty = 0;
}
else if (gameMode == 'medium'){
    gameDifficulty = 1;
}
else{
    gameDifficulty = 2;
} //this will state which array the questions will come from


function questionBox(x){ // This allows me to add my buttons to the box. I can pass a id through x
    return document.getElementById(x);
}


function displayQuestion(){
    box = questionBox("quizquestions"); //this will allow me to add the questions and answers into the box I created in HTML.
    if(questionNumber >= 8) {
        console.log(score);
        return false;
    }
    
    currentQuestion = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][0];
    optionA = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][1];//gameDifficulty will stay the same throughout the game and is set when asking which difficulty you want to play
    optionB = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][2];//questionNumber will change everytime you answer a questions it is used to select the next set of questions in the multidimentional array
    optionC = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][3];
    optionD = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][4];
    box.innerHTML += "<h2>"+currentQuestion+"</h2><br>";//This will display the variable defined above.
    box.innerHTML += "<input type = 'radio' name = 'option' value = 'A'> "+optionA+"<br>";//The imput type defines what kind of button it is.
    box.innerHTML += "<input type = 'radio' name = 'option' value = 'B'> "+optionB+"<br>";//the name and value will help me check weather they clicked the correct answer
    box.innerHTML += "<input type = 'radio' name = 'option' value = 'C'> "+optionC+"<br>";//the <br> is used to make all the questions on separate lines. This makes the page look more tidy
    box.innerHTML += "<input type = 'radio' name = 'option' value = 'D'> "+optionD+"<br><br><br>";
    box.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkOptions ()'>Check </button>";//This is just a regular button. 
}

function checkOptions(){
let correctAnswer = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][5];
    options = document.getElementsByName("option");
    for(let i=0; i<options.length; i++){
        if (options[i].checked){
            option = options[i].value;
        }
    }
    if (option == correctAnswer){
        score++;
    }
    questionNumber++;
    displayQuestion();
}

window.addEventListener("load", displayQuestion, false);
```

Comment: Please share the HTML too and I think the problem is you having multiple of elements that overlaps.

Comment: @Theygen I have added the HTML. There isn't much but I'm trying to keep as much code as possible in the JavaScript. Hope this helps you figure out my problem. I'm clueless.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your box.innerHTML to empty before adding anything:

```
function displayQuestion(){
    box = questionBox("quizquestions"); //this will allow me to add the questions and answers into the box I created in HTML.
    if(questionNumber >= 8) {
        console.log(score);
        return false;
    }
    
    currentQuestion = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][0];
    optionA = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][1];//gameDifficulty will stay the same throughout the game and is set when asking which difficulty you want to play
    optionB = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][2];//questionNumber will change everytime you answer a questions it is used to select the next set of questions in the multidimentional array
    optionC = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][3];
    optionD = questions[gameDifficulty][questionNumber][4];
    box.innerHTML = ""; // THIS IS THE CHANGE
    box.innerHTML += "<h2>"+currentQuestion+"</h2><br>";//This will display the variable defined above.
    box.innerHTML += "<input type = 'radio' name = 'option' value = 'A'> "+optionA+"<br>";//The imput type defines what kind of button it is.
    box.innerHTML += "<input type = 'radio' name = 'option' value = 'B'> "+optionB+"<br>";//the name and value will help me check weather they clicked the correct answer
    box.innerHTML += "<input type = 'radio' name = 'option' value = 'C'> "+optionC+"<br>";//the <br> is used to make all the questions on separate lines. This makes the page look more tidy
    box.innerHTML += "<input type = 'radio' name = 'option' value = 'D'> "+optionD+"<br><br><br>";
    box.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkOptions ()'>Check </button>";//This is just a regular button. 
}
```

The change I made is marked with THIS IS THE CHANGE